# Lyx Graphics context menu "Edit Externally" is not working (Windows 7)

Tags: graphics, lyx, windows, viewers

- Insert an image using the Lyx menu `Insert->Graphics`.
- Right click on the image preview and click `Edit externally`
- Current Behavior: The viewer is launched but the file is not opened.
- Expected Behavior: The viewer should be launched with the image file open.

**Edit:**
I observed that in Lyx:Graphics "Settings:" context menu, the "File:" field has forward slashes.  So, if the viewer is not capable of opening full path arguments with forward slashes, then the image file will not be opened. Is this a bug in Lyx.

Comment: If you think it is a bug, create a ticket at http://www.lyx.org/trac/wiki/BugTrackerHome, or raise the issue at the mailing list first (http://www.lyx.org/MailingLists).

Comment: created a new ticket http://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/8892

Comment: Bug reports are off-topic, I'm afraid.